# Is there any way to extract data model from parsed template or xml?

Tags: freemarker

I have output of parsed template, is there any way i get data model extracted from parsed template based on template with placeholders?

template.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Welcome!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome ${user}!</h1>
<p>Our latest product:
  <a href="${latestProduct.url}">${latestProduct.name}</a>!
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

parsed template

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Welcome!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome Big Joe!</h1>
<p>Our latest product:
  <a href="products/greenmouse.html">green mouse</a>!
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

so is there any way to get data model for the template?

template + data model = output will give parsed template so is there something like

template - output = data model ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't, as it's fundamentally an one-way process. If you just have `<#if someCondition>${x}<#else>${y}</#if>`, which is a fairly trivial template, it's already impossible to tell if what you have in the output is the value of `x` or `y`.

Comment: Thanks for response but i have already realized that it can not be done.